# Mybatis collection call procedure with out params

Tags: collections, mybatis

I want make this complex object with Mybatis.

```
public class UserInfo {
    public Integer clientId;
    public String userName;

    public List<Device> deviceList;
}
```

First two field return one procedure:

```
procedure getUserInfo(pClientId in number, pRes out sys_refcursor);
```

Third field (deviceList) return another procedure:

```
procedure getDevices(pClientId in number, pRes out sys_refcursor);
```

My java code:

```
SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession(); 
mapper = session.getMapper(UserInfoMapper.class); 

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
ResultSet rs = null;
params.put("clientId", clientId);
params.put("result", rs);

mapper.getUserInfo(params);

info = ((ArrayList<UserInfo>)params.get("result")).get(0);
```

UserInfoMapper:

```
public interface UserInfoMapper {
    void getUserInfo(Map<String, Object> params);
}
```

How I must write UserInfoMapper.xml in order to solve my problem? 
Now it looks like this:

```
<mapper namespace="UserInfoMapper">
    <resultMap id="UserInfoResult" type="UserInfo">
        <id property="clientId" column="clientId"/>
        <result property="userName" column="userName"/>
        <collection property="deviceList" ofType="Device" 
                    column="clientId=clientId" select="getDeviceList"/> 
    </resultMap>

    <resultMap id="DeviceListResult" type="Device">
        <result property="deviceName" column="DEVICE_NAME"/>
    </resultMap>

    <select id="getUserInfo" statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="java.util.Map">
        CALL MESSAGE_SERVER.getUserInfo(
            #{clientId, mode=IN},
            #{result, jdbcType=CURSOR, javaType=java.sql.ResultSet, mode=OUT, resultMap=UserInfoResult}        
        )   
    </select>

    <select id="getDeviceList" statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="java.util.Map" >
        CALL MESSAGE_SERVER.getDevices(
            #{clientId, mode=IN},
            #{result, jdbcType=CURSOR, javaType=java.sql.ResultSet, mode=OUT, resultMap=DeviceListResult}        
        )   
    </select>

</mapper>
```

Especially interested in the question: how to collection select result gets to the final object? How to make this object link?

Now turns out so that first two field return successfully. But deviceList is empty.

Comment: forget declaring a ResultSet, this is implementation detail, just `params.put("result", null);` and the 'result' key might even not be required to exist. Use List instead of ArrayList: variables declared types must be as abstract as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The device list is null because it is actually never assigned. Indeed a stored procedure call is not a select returning a result, the result is bound to an output variable, you have well understood and applied it for 'getUserInfo'. It cannot be done with a single mapper call if using stored procedures.

Here is how I would modify the mapper: no more collection/nested select.

The deviceList result can be bound directly in UserInfo object that must then be used as parameter.

```
<mapper namespace="UserInfoMapper">
    <resultMap id="UserInfoResult" type="UserInfo">
        <id property="clientId" column="clientId"/>
        <result property="userName" column="userName"/>
    </resultMap>

    <resultMap id="DeviceListResult" type="Device">
        <result property="deviceName" column="DEVICE_NAME"/>
    </resultMap>

    <select id="getUserInfo" statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="java.util.Map">
        CALL MESSAGE_SERVER.getUserInfo(
            #{clientId, mode=IN},
            #{result, jdbcType=CURSOR, javaType=java.sql.ResultSet, mode=OUT, resultMap=UserInfoResult}        
        )   
    </select>

    <select id="loadDeviceList" statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="UserInfo" >
        CALL MESSAGE_SERVER.getDevices(
            #{clientId, mode=IN},
            #{deviceList, jdbcType=CURSOR, javaType=java.sql.ResultSet, mode=OUT, resultMap=DeviceListResult}        
        )   
    </select>
</mapper>
```

and at the end of the java , add:

```
mapper.getDeviceList(info);
```

Then `info` will be filled with deviceList.

Comment: Thank you, at first I did so. I just thought that this problem can be resolved in a single mapper call.